# Set Storage Account key using an Arm Template

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to be able to *set* the access keys of a azure storage account using an ARM Template. I have looked at the quick start templates which don't have any examples. This does not give me any examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts and googling reveals lots of examples of how to get the dynamically generated keys.

Comment: As Gaurav Mantri said, you could not use a custom account key. Do you want to template to generate access key? If yes, you could do this.

Comment: No, I want to be able to set the key so I don't then have to update the key which is used in multiple places across multiple systems. What you are saying is basically I can never regenerate my server setup because the access keys will change.

Comment: As Gaurav Mantri said, currently, it is impossible.

Comment: Major flaw with Azure infrastructure as code IMHO, I can set access keys for azure service bus but not blob storage? Why? Where do I complain? P.s. Thanks for your help, it is appreciated even if I'm not happy with the answer :)

Comment: `I can set access keys for azure service bus but not blob storage?` - If I am not mistaken, you can't do that for Azure Service Bus as well. Azure generates a key for you there as well.

Comment: {
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
      "name": "[variables('servicebus_AuthorizationRules_RootManageSharedAccessKey')]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "keyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
        "claimType": "SharedAccessKey",
        "claimValue": "None",
        "primaryKey": "[parameters('managePrimaryKey')]",
        "secondaryKey": "[parameters('manageSecondaryKey')]",
        "rights": [
          "Listen",
          "Manage",
          "Send" ETC

Comment: Thank You! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to set the access keys of a azure storage account
>   using an ARM Template.

Simple answer is that you can't. Currently Azure Storage Service generates access keys for you automatically. You can't choose/specify a custom account key.